# excel VBA - Copy row above, with formula | From Sheet 1 Insert into Sheets 4, 6 | Delete row on Sheet 1 also deleting row Sheet 4, 6

Tags: excel-formula

Sheet 1 copy down code works on Sheet 1. The same code does not work on other sheets. The delete row code deletes the Sheet 1 row however the Sheet 4 and 6 row deletion create errors across other rows on Sheet 4 and 6.

I need the VBA code to copy the row above when the command button is clicked as if I inserted a row and copied the row above into that new row. However, I need the new row to ignore the value in the copied row cells that have formulas, leaving only the copied formula in the new cell.

I need the VBA Code for Delete Row to delete a row on sheet 1 and delete that same row on Sheets 4 and 6 without creating errors across other row.

Current Code:

```
Sub CopyDown()

    SelRow = ActiveCell.Row
        HideButtons
        MoveButtons
    
    With ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Range(SelRow & ":" & SelRow).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Range(SelRow & ":" & SelRow).Insert xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        DisplayButtons
    
    End With
    
    Calculations.Range(SelRow - 4 & ":" & SelRow - 4).Copy
    Calculations.Range(SelRow - 4 & ":" & SelRow - 4).Insert xlDown
```

```
Sub DeleteRow()

    SelRow = ActiveCell.Row
    MoveButtons
    ActiveSheet.Range(SelRow & ":" & SelRow).EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & SelRow).Select
    DisplayButtons

    Calculations.Range(SelRow - 4 & ":" & SelRow - 4).EntireRow.Delete
    CostSummary.Range(SelRow - 4 & ":" & SelRow - 4).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Copy Down:

I have adjusted the formula on the sheet 1 (Base Year), Cell J11 to read:

=INDIRECT("Calculations!I" & ROW()-4)

Sheet 4 is titled Calculations and the input data for the Sheet 1 cell is found in column I.

On Sheets 2 (Option Yr) I adjusted the formula of Cell J11 to read:

=INDIRECT("Calculations!I" & ROW()+36)

On Sheet 4 (Calculations) the input data for Cell J11 was adjusted from -4 to +36. This adkustment corresponds with the J11 cell of the Option yr.

Delete Row:

I do not know of a solution to try since the VBA code deletes the row correctly on Sheet 1 (IGCE) and on the correct Calculations sheet table associated with the IGCE.

Comment: BTW, you can avoid the volatility of INDIRECT with INDEX: `=INDEX(Calculations!$I:$I,ROW()-4)`

Comment: Hi Scott.  I input the Index formula and the row being copied changed to a value of "0" . The new row copied down contains the cell data of the copied row and the formula looks the same however, when 88 is changed to 100 the fourmula cell doesn't update.